# YII2 how to get each record after joinwith

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to get each record in an active record after multiple joinWiths?

```
$model = \common\models\opcr\OpcrKra::find()
         ->joinWith('opcrRoObjectives')
         ->joinWith('opcrRoObjectives.opcrFdObjectives')
         ->joinWith('opcrRoObjectives.opcrFdObjectives.opcrIndividuals');
```

I get a `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

```
foreach ($model->all() as $row) {
      echo "<tr>"
      . "<td></td>"
      . "<td>" . $row->kra . "</td>"
      . "<td>" . $row->opcrRoObjectives->id . "</td>" // error here
      . "</tr>";
      }
```

I tried to display the `$row->count()` and it gave me just the exact number of records I expected.

Comment: Are you sure that opcrRoObjectives exists for each OpcrKra records? 'joinWith' applies a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using the [eager loading](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/834/relational-query-lazy-loadnig-and-eager-loading-in-yii-2-0/).

```
    $authors = Author::find()->with('posts')->all();  // fetches the authors with their posts
    foreach($authors as $author) {
    echo "<h2>Author : " . $author->name . "</h2>";
    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($author->posts as $post) {  // no query executed here
        echo "<li>" . $post->title . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just try this solution:

```
$model = \common\models\opcr\OpcrKra::find()
     ->joinWith('opcrRoObjectives')
     ->joinWith('opcrRoObjectives.opcrFdObjectives')
     ->joinWith('opcrRoObjectives.opcrFdObjectives.opcrIndividuals')
$result =  $model->asArray()->all();
```

Then in your view:

```
foreach ($model as $row) {
  echo "<tr>"
  . "<td></td>"
  . "<td>" . $row->kra . "</td>"
  . "<td>" . $row['opcrRoObjectives']['id'] . "</td>"
  . "</tr>";
  }
```